# Rotate Screen, Not Working in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, display, rotate

I am using Windows 7.

I tried to rotate my screen, but it is not working. I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow</kbd>, and it didn't work. I opened graphics resolution, but there is no option to rotate the screen.  But, the above steps all work on my Dell laptop and desktop.

I am using a Sony VAIO and a Lenovo laptop, with Intel Graphics Media Accelerator driver.

How do I solve this problem?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you download and install [iRotate](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/Video-Tweak/iRotate.shtml). It rockz.

In case that does not work: if your driver supports screen rotation at all, you may be using a generic driver that would not enable to use the screen rotation features of your graphics card.

Please tell us more about your exact graphics card model, mobile PC model, and driver version.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After installing iRotate I click on (90,180,270.....) but gives a error sound and nothing happens. I am usuing Intel core 2 duo..

Comment: @Aritra , find and install driver for your display

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you [Find/download Lenovo Drivers](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/default.page)  -OR-  [Find/download Sony Drivers](http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/select-system.pl?model_type_group_id=10)

I recommend you first find your model laptop, then find the graphics driver. I'm assume you're using a generic graphics driver. If it still won't rotate, your laptops may not support screen rotation. I really hope this was able to help you, I know how frustrating simple things like this can be.